# Is it possible to keep the information unchanged after switching to different views in xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4.2

In xcode4.2 , I use single view application for my program. My program requires the users to enter the answers for different views. When the users answer the questions and switch to different views and then come back, I find that all the answers are disappeared. Could it be possible to keep the answer after switching views? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults for lasting memory